# Why is JSONObject.accumulate() affecting the values of other keys?

Tags: java, arrays, json

I'm writing a program that collects the counter results of a sorting algorithm. I'm storing the values in a JSONObject so I can compute averages and such later on.

```
public void addCounters(String sortName, Integer arraySize, long[] counters){
    results.getJSONObject(sortName).getJSONObject("testresults").accumulate(arraySize.toString(), counters);
    System.out.println(results);
}
```

As you can see, it should be appending each result to the key that applies to it.

The first output is correct..

> {"inSort":{"repetitionspertest":100,"description":"Best Case","numofcounters":2,"testresults":{"1000":[998,0]}}}

The second output appends correctly..

> {"inSort":{"repetitionspertest":100,"description":"Best Case","numofcounters":2,"testresults":{"1000":[[998,0],[998,0]]}}}

But when a new key is added, it changes ALL of the arrays. Even the ones in different keys..

> {"inSort":{"repetitionspertest":100,"description":"Best Case","numofcounters":2,"testresults":{"1000":[[1998,0],[1998,0]],"2000":[1998,0]}}}

You can see that the values in key "1000" are changing to 1998 instead of 998.
I've even tried writing my own equivalent to the .accumulate() method but to no avail.

I'm assuming this is to do with referencing the same array in memory, but I have no idea how to solve this!

Please can anyone propose a solution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's because you're using the same object for "1000" and "2000".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your method that calls `addCounters()`. The reference you're passing in the parameter `long[] counters` is being initialized once to `new long[2]` and mistakenly reused. You must initialize the variable to a new long array each time you execute the sorting algorithm.

Comment: Excellent, thanks ever so much. After much tinkering I also found that replacing counters with counters.clone() worked too.